# java applet - Do some action migrates away from web page?

Tags: java, applet

I want to do some action in java applet if user migrates  away from applet web page to some other web  page of my site..How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have to override the `stop()` or `destroy()` applet life cycle method.

Comment: `stop()` should be called when the browser is minimized or the user changes tabs.